# Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I'm trying to prove that if  $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \phantom{2}$ is a function that  verifies :

$\exists\, K \in \mathbb{R^+}, \phantom{1}\forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}: \lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert \le K\lvert \cos y - \cos x \rvert$

then $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$

Maybe it could be useful the fact that I recently proved that f is a Lipschitz function since  by mean value theorem 
$\dfrac{|\cos y - \cos x|}{|y-x|}\le 1 \implies |\cos y - \cos x|\le|x-y|$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} $ as $\cos$ is differentiable over all of $\mathbb R$.

So 
$$\exists\, K \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}: |f(y)-f(x)| \le K|\cos y - \cos x|\le K|x-y|$$

The proof seems easy but I'm not sure how can I prove it, any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't taking $y = x+2\pi$ give this to you immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $y=x+2\pi.$ We get $|f(x+2\pi)-f(x)|\leq K|\cos(x+2\pi)-\cos x|=0$ as $\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Substitute $y= x+2\pi$ in the given inequality.